# Resolution handling in QMainWindow

Tags: qt, screen-resolution, qmainwindow

I've a `QMainWwindow`, and I've fixed its size.

i.e. I've set Minimum and maximum size of the window to the same number.

Could anyone tell me whether this will be a problem if I'm to use this in another screen with a different resolution, and if so, how am I to handle it?

Kindly advise, and also if there's another way ( perhaps more elegant) to set the size of the `QMainWindow`.

***UPDATE :***

I have a `QMainWindow` with a `QTableView` as a widget, amongst others. When I expand the main Window, the tableview does not, and it leaves an ungainly blank space, so I fixed the size.

If I were to make it resizeable, how do I expand the `QTableView` widget, alongwith the `QMainWindow`. I have a  Central Widget, this widget has a vertical box layout, and to this layout I've added the 3 widgets, one with `QGridlayout`, one horizontal line, and the other `QTableView`. The QTableView, on its own, is not inside a layout.

I'd imagined this would be sufficient to expand the table too, once `QMainWindow` were expanded, or reduced, but it doesn't happen.

How do i go about it, i.e., expanding the `QTableView` as well?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594969/get-physical-screen-size-in-qt should help you

Answer (score 1):

It will be a problem if you fix the size to one that is larger than the screen can handle. There are various ways to scale the size of a window according to the screen size. I recommend using `QApplication::desktop()`, which will return the desktop widget (you may need to `#include <QDesktopWidget>`. Note that this widget can actually encompass multiple screens, so if you just want the current screen, you can just do:

```
QRect screenGeometry = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
```

You could alternatively use `QDesktopWidget::availableGeometry()`.

It is worth mentioning that among Qt users, I think there is a general dislike of fixed size windows. Most recommend taking full advantage of the Qt layout system, which provides lots of flexibility for resizing windows. I'm not saying you should definitely do this, because all projects are different, but it could be worth looking into.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll certainly check it that way. I have a `QMainWindow` with a `QTableView` as a widget, amongst others. When I expand the main Window, the tableview does not, and it leaves an ungainly blank space, so I fixed the size. If I were to make it resizeable, how do I expand the `QTableView` widget, alongwith the `QMainWindow`, please?

Comment: Is your QTableView inside of a QLayout?

Comment: No. Central Widget, this widget has a vertical box layout, and to this layout I've added the 3 widgets, one with `QGridlayout`, one horizontal line, and the other `QTableView`. The `QTableView`, on its own, is not inside a layout. Should I add a separate layout to `QTableView`, then? Which one should I add?

Comment: So you have a main window with a central widget, and the central widget has a vertical box layout with (1) another layout, (2), a horizontal line, and (3) the table view. That sounds right to me. You don't need to add the table view to another layout if it is already inside the QVBoxLayout. Something else must be wrong. Have you tried setting the table view's size policy to something like `MinimumExpanding`?

Comment: Uh..huh...Deosn't work. `QMainWindow` has a central widget. Widget has a `VBoxLayout`. 3 widgets are added to this layout, one a widget have a `QGridLayout`, other a line,and third a `QTableView`. When I expand the Window, both the first widget ( with its own layout), and the line expand, but the `QTableView` does not. I have not set any special properties, size related, for the `QTableView`. What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: One last suggestion. Try this: `QSizePolicy policy = tableView->sizePolicy(); policy.setVerticalStretch(1); policy.setHorizontalStretch(1); tableView->setSizePolicy(policy);`

Comment: Nope. That didn't work either. The table just won't expand, or reduce if I expand, or reduce, the `QMainWindow`. Always stays the same size, and doesn't budge.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code? There must be something wrong. It should probably be a separate question.

Comment: Relevant code is in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297182/qtableview-not-expanding-reducing-when-qmainwindow-is-resized)