# Get screen diagonal size in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, size, pixel, diagonal

Is there any way to get size of diagonal of the screen (in inches) in Qt?
I need it to calculate how big is my pixel. Or maybe I can get pixel size directly?

Comment: It would be impossible IMO. Think about it. The computer can tell how many pixels are on a monitor by asking the monitor. The computer can't ask the monitor how big it is because the monitor doesn't know that.

Comment: So maybe I can take DPI of screen?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594969/get-physical-screen-size-in-qt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get screen size, you can use [QScreen::physicalSize](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#physicalSize-prop).

Also, you can get the number of pixels per inch, by using [QScreen::physicalDotsPerInch](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#physicalDotsPerInch-prop)

```
QScreen *screen = qApp->screens().at(0);
qDebug() << screen->geometry() << screen->physicalSize() << screen->physicalDotsPerInch();
```